# Partial update of an object with typescirpt

Tags: typescript

What I am trying to achieve is to create a utility function that excepts an instance and an object and updates the instance with the provided input fields values. Here is the utility function:

```
function updateEntity<T, K extends keyof T>(
    entity: T,
    updateInput: { [key in K]: T[K] },
  ): void {
    return Object.keys(updateInput).forEach((key) => {
      entity[key as K] = updateInput[key as K];
    });
}
```

and here I have an instance and an update interface:

```
class Animal {
  name: string = 'no name';
  isMale: boolean = false;
}

type Input = Partial<{
  name: string;
}>;

const input: Input = {
  name: 'str'
};

const cat = new Animal();

updateEntity(cat, input); // input is an error
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<{ name: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

I don't think that I fully understand the error message. My intent was to partially update the original instance with the provided input.

The input must be a subset of the original instance (no extra fields).

Here is a link to the playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBYAUNa8YyApgFzQQAuATovAObQC80A5PAPYFHGsDcufIggBZNGWgAjDhxDEw8ZtABmaCMQE4AvrlyUAngAdi0AJLxDAV0pKACmGqVEaADzY83EuSq0GmrQB8mrjKlvDAThyKloYAJmCUxACi8E4GLgAqADTQANLQxAAeifCxMADWxPocytAZAQAUgvgFqYgG5NnN%20DHxieZWlOQY0ADalfrQdHkAup2juTPQWlnNAJTkAG4ciLGY3dDUxJSW1IoA8pIAVsQRAHQTEA29CcQD1mt3yhzUSWDAAAsGg0JmtmAF9h4Wq00vpxlVoJBZkoXv0LNZ4ZMkYtNNCtGt-LocMAolQpuihmYKUp3PhCF42D5WLgtMFiaSbMAEkp4MQAO5wJCoEANAlE1HJNoGBpcyg5OiDAlAA)

What am I missing?

Comment: Not related, but your Partial seems a bit overkill, `name?: string` would have just done the same, did you mean `type Input = Partial<Animal>`, or if you only did need the name `type Input = Partial<Pick<Animal, 'name'>>`  Otherwise you could define name as string in one place and boolean in the other,  it seems much cleaner to have name type only defined once.

Comment: It's just a simple example, though I could do a `Partial<Animal>` I want to have a dedicated interface/type

Answer (score 1):

Use non-null assertion. When you hover on the `updateInput` parameter, its type will be `{ [key in K]?: T[K] | undefined }` because the fields that are absent will be `undefined`. TypeScript still believes that `updateInput[key]` can be `undefined` rather than `T[K]` but we are pretty sure that `updateInput[key]` can only be of type `T[K]`.

```
function updateEntity<T, K extends keyof T>(
  entity: T,
  updateInput: { [key in K]?: T[K] },
): void {
  for (const key in updateInput) {
    entity[key] = updateInput[key]!;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will allow fields outside of T. See cide here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBYAUNa8YyApgFzQQAuATovAObQC80A5PAPYFHGsDcufIggBZNGWgAjDhxDEw8ZtABmaCMQE4AvrlyUAngAdi0AJLxDAV0pKACmGqVEaADzY83EuSq0Gm-GCSwOQAjABMAMwANLhaAHyauMqW8MBOHIqWhgAmYJTEAKLwTgYuACpR0ADS0MQAHvnw2TAA1sT6HMrQZXEAFIK1xYgG5BUDWbn55laU5BjQANpt+tB01QC6APyjC1Xr0FoxOACU5ABuHIjZmAPKHNTQvcAZVNDLq5k5ecTT1sc3HnwxCGBiW7X2LAm31+lDB+nWAEJ-AdYrocM94K86DNyDClO58IQvGwfKxYol0S8bMA8kp4MQAO5wJCoEC9Y4UqH5IolfRPPKVbF-PjQAD0orM0BAiDa0EoXAAFmAziYFLVqNR7h85UrqZBVTBAsBVjBODYwG92tqaTZegyFYhgAqTdA1QgUGhjkA